# Html and momentjs design problem - add spacing to elements with inline css

Tags: html, knockout.js, momentjs

I have following code:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="start" name="start" data-bind="datepicker: DateTimeFilterFrom,event: { change: applyChangeDate } " />
    <input type="text" id="end" name="end" data-bind="datepicker: DateTimeFilterTo,event: { change: applyChangeDate } "/>
</div>
```

and when I go to my chrome I see joined two input fields with add calendar icon.

[image]

However, the computed HTML is preety much flatten (icons and input types are all in the same div)

I want to add a little bit spacing between calendar icon from the first and the second input type

computed HTML looks like:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="start" name="start" data-bind="datepicker: DateTimeFilterFrom,event: { change: applyChangeDate } " class="hasDatepicker">
    <img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="/content/img/calendar.png" alt="..." title="...">
    <input type="text" id="end" name="end" data-bind="datepicker: DateTimeFilterTo,event: { change: applyChangeDate } " class="hasDatepicker">
    <img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="/content/img/calendar.png" alt="..." title="...">
</div>
```

Comment: I kinda don't get it, don't you just want to style it with CSS?

Comment: yes, I want. with inline css.

Comment: I found solution to add margin-left to second input-type, but is there any better solutions?

Comment: you could set margin-right on the calendar icon, but thats clearly the same. Or you could use something like ```display: grid; justify-content:space-between;``` to the parent element